# Get a PsiFile inside a Gradle plugin task

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I am working on a Gradle plugin that will/should inspect some code using Psi  (https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/architectural_overview/psi.html). I know how to use Psi if it was an IntelliJ plugin, but I don't know where to start in the context of a Gradle task.

The Gradle task API would look like this:

```
generateRibStateTree {
    rootRibBuilderFile = file("$rootDir/app/src/main/java/com/coca/jorge/root/RootBuilder.kt")
    reportDirectoryFile = file("$rootDir/reports") // your desired directory here
}
```

The goal is to receive the `rooRibBuilderFile` in a `java.io.File` object, but then I do not know how to start parsing that file with Psi. Any ideas?

Comment: You basically need to start the platform in your Gradle plugin (probably similar to running tests in intellij-community). But really? What do you actually want to do with Psi?

Comment: With Psi, what I want to do is, given the rootRibBuilderFile, scan the file for internal interfaces that declare some other children "ribs" (I am using a framework from Uber called RIBs), so I can create a visual representation of the project architecture.